# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{a_1} + e^\frac{a_2}{2} + \cdots + e^\frac{a_n}{n} - n}{\log{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to solve the limit:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{a_1} + e^\frac{a_2}{2} + \cdots + e^\frac{a_n}{n} - n}{\log{n}}$$

Where $a_n \rightarrow a$.

Because $\log{n}$ is monotone we can use Stolz-Cesàro, where the equivalent limit is:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^\frac{a_{n + 1}}{n + 1} - 1}{\log \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)}
& = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n \left( e^\frac{a_{n + 1}}{n + 1} - 1 \right)}{ n \log \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)} \\
& = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n \left( \left( 1 + \frac{a_{n + 1}}{n + 1} + o(\frac{1}{n^2}) \right) - 1 \right) }{\log \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n} \\
& = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{\log{e}} \\
& = a
\end{align}

Using Taylor expansion of $e$.

Is this correct? Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: From https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info: This tag should be used when you have a proposed solution to a problem and have *specific concerns* or doubts about the validity of that solution. A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough

Comment: Even without the [solution-verification] tag: “Is this correct?” without identifying precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so, is considered off-topic (too broad). See also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4597/42969 on Meta.

Comment: I will keep it in mind

Comment: You should prove the more general statement that if $x_n\to x>0$ then $n(x_n^{1/n}-1)\to\log x$. Here $x_n=e^{a_n} $.